# Import specific table from sql file

Tags: sql, mysql

i have sql file that i want do 2 work with that

I want to know 2 way

1- is import specific table from large sql file into my db

2- import all sql except one table

Comment: They is no way outside of grabbing the portions you are interested in into a different file.  That is unless there are some tools out there that can do this.